# Groovy Generics problems with <T extends SuperClass>

Tags: generics, groovy

```
class TestClass <T extends SuperClass>{
 public List<T> doSmth(){
    ///....
    List testObjects = []
    testObjects.add(new T(arg))
   return testObjects;
 }
}

class SuperClass{

}
class A extends SuperClass{
 A(Arg arg){
  ....
}
class B extends SuperClass{
 B(Arg arg){
  ....
}

////////test
class Main{
 List <A> a
 List <B> b

 Main(){
  this.a = new TestClass<A>().doSmth()
  this.b = new TestClass<B>().doSmth()
 }
}
```

Exception found (groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for SuperClass) on line

```
 testObjects.add(new T(arg))
```

This is quite correct coz SuperClass have no constructor. But sub-classes have one and all of them have the same signature, arg with the same type.

can some one help me to find a solution to my problem?

Comment: Both A and B classes have the same type of arguments in constructors.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your code doesn't work is not matching constructors of `A` and `B`. The reason is missing constructor that accepts string in `SuperClass`. 
`new T()` doesn't work as you expect. In your code it becomes `new SuperClass(arg)`. The following code demonstrates it

```
class TestClass <T extends SuperClass> {
    public void doSmth(){
        println new T().class.simpleName;
    }
}

class SuperClass{}
class A extends SuperClass{}
class B extends SuperClass{}

new TestClass<A>().doSmth()
new TestClass<B>().doSmth()
new TestClass<String>().doSmth() //even this works
```

Output is

```
SuperClass
SuperClass
SuperClass
```

`TestClass <T>` will print `Object`. `TestClass <T extends A>` will print `A` and so on.

Groovy doesn't have generic type information in runtime. Groovy even doesn't do compile type checking (example with `new TestClass<String>()`). But it keeps some info to make `new T()` work.

> Java's generics implementation incorporates a feature known as "type erasure" which "throws away" generic type information after completing static type checking. This allows Java to easily integrate with legacy "non-generics" libraries. Groovy currently does a little further and throws away generics information "at the source level". Generics information is kept within signatures where appropriate http://web.archive.org/web/20150102195947/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to create a new instance of the generic type with `new T`. So you'll need to work around that problem.

One way to work around it is to include a closure parameter in `doSmth()` that creates the instance for you.

```
public List<T> doSmth(Closure newT) {
    List testObjects = []
    testObjects.add(newT(arg))
    return testObjects;
}
```

and provide the code to create new instance when calling the method:

```
Main() {
    this.a = new TestClass<A>().doSmth { new A(it) }
    this.b = new TestClass<B>().doSmth { new B(it) }
}
```